# Where to download the latest Scala API documentation?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Since Scala 2.10.2, I can't find the download link for its API documentation.  Is this an intentional omission?  Where can I download it?

Alternatively, what is the exact `scalac` command to generate the same one with http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html ? (e.g. I don't know which source jars I have to include.)

Comment: See [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-docs-2.10.2.zip) at [this page](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.10.2.html)

Comment: Thanks! How did you find that URL?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

See [API docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-docs-2.10.2.zip) at [this page](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.10.2.html).

How to find:

[scala-lang.org](http://www.scala-lang.org/) -> [Download](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/) -> [All downloads](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html) -> [Scala 2.10.2](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.10.2.html).

Comment: Currently, [Download](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/) => [Current {version} Release](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/2.11.0.html)(2.11.0) => (scroll down) => [scala-docs-{version}.txz](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.0/scala-docs-2.11.0.txz)(2.11.0)

Comment: API docs for 2.11.4 => [.zip format](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.4/scala-docs-2.11.4.zip?_ga=1.167793953.1277213528.1414749615)  [.txz format](http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.4/scala-docs-2.11.4.txz?_ga=1.167793953.1277213528.1414749615)

Answer (score 9):

The API Docs download is hard to find because if you just go to the link for the current version of scala the menu item named other resources which has as a subitem, the API docs download isn't there.

So, to find the api docs:

http://www.scala-lang.org/
download
All Downloads
click on latest version or version you want
scroll down to other resources and you will see API DOCS

if you go to:
http://www.scala-lang.org/
download
the the latest version pops up but without the other resources at the bottom.

This is why it is hard to locate.

Answer (score 3):

- 2.11.8 docs in .txz format: http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.8/scala-docs-2.11.8.txz
- 2.11.8 docs in .zip format: http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/2.11.8/scala-docs-2.11.8.zip

As of March 2015, you need to take the approach in @michael_n's comment:

```
http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/{version}/scala-docs-{version}.txz
http://downloads.typesafe.com/scala/{version}/scala-docs-{version}.zip
```